# Which numbers can a floating point variable store exactly?

Tags: floating-point, precision

As far as my knowledge goes there are numbers which floating point variables can store exactly such as 0.

So if I have the code:

{

float var=0;

printf("%f", var);

}

I would get as output:

`0.0000000000000000000`

But I have heard that there are other numbers that also can be stored exactly using floating point variable.

How do I determine if a variable can be stored exactly using floating point variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

A finite number can be represented in the IEEE-754 “double precision” format if and only if it equals *M*•2<sup>*e*</sup> for some integers *M* and *e* such that −2<sup>53</sup> < *M* < +2<sup>53</sup> and −1074 ≤ *e* ≤ 971.

For example, 3.125 can be represented because it equals 25•2<sup>−3</sup>, and 25 is an integer in (−2<sup>53</sup>, +2<sup>53</sup>), and −3 is an integer in [−1074, 971].

### Discussion

Generally, a floating-point format represents finite numbers as ±*d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> where:

- ± means either + or −,
- *b* is a positive integer base that is fixed for the format, usually 2 or 10,
- *p*, called the precision, is the number of base-*b* digits in the *significand*,
- *d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub> (example: 1.2345) is the significand of the floating-point representation, and each *d*<sub>*i*</sub> is an integer with 0 ≤ *d*<sub>*i*</sub> < *b*, and
- *e* is an integer with *e*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *e* ≤ *e*<sub>max</sub>, where *e*<sub>min</sub> and *e*<sub>max</sub> are fixed limits for the format.

Note the radix point “.” after *d*<sub>0</sub>. This means the significand is in [0, *b*) and has *p*−1 digits after the radix point. (“[0, *b*)” denotes a half-open interval that includes 0 but excludes *b*.) Sometimes floating-point formats are described with the radix point in different positions, either before the first digit, .*d*<sub>0</sub>*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>, or after the last digit, *d*<sub>0</sub>*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>. These are equivalent mathematically:

- *d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> = .*d*<sub>0</sub>*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>•*b*<sup>*e*+1</sup> = *d*<sub>0</sub>*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>1−*p*</sub>.•*b*<sup>*e*+1−*p*</sup>.

The exponent limits *e*<sub>min</sub> and *e*<sub>max</sub> would be adjusted to match the position used. With the radix-point on the right, the significand is an integer, and this is convenient for using number theory in analysis and proofs about floating-point.

Some floating-point formats may require *d*<sub>0</sub> to be non-zero. This is rare now. Representations in which *d*<sub>0</sub> is non-zero are said to be in *normal form*, and representations in which *d*<sub>0</sub> is zero are said be *denormalized*. A non-zero number that can be represented in the denormalized form of a format but is too small to be represented in its normal format is said to be *subnormal*.

For the IEEE-754 binary64 format, also called “double precision,” *b* is 2, *p* is 53, *e*<sub>min</sub> is −1022, and *e*<sub>max</sub> is 1023.

Using the integer-significand scaling, the exponent minimum and maximum are −1074 and 971. Then we can say a finite number can be represented in this format if and only if it equals *M*•2<sup>*e*</sup> for some integers *M* and *e* such that −2<sup>53</sup> < *M* < +2<sup>53</sup> and −1074 ≤ *e* ≤ 971.

For single precision, the binary32 format, −2<sup>24</sup> < *M* < +2<sup>24</sup> and −149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104.

These formats also have encodings that represent −∞, +∞, and special NaN (Not a Number) values.

### Example of an Unrepresentable Number

3⅓ cannot be represented because 3⅓•2<sup>*p*</sup> is not an integer for any integer *p*. If there were integers *M* and *e* such that 3⅓ = *M*•2<sup>*e*</sup>, we could multiply each side by 3 to get 10 = 3•*M*•2<sup>*e*</sup>, and then 5 = 3•*M*•2<sup>*e*−1</sup>. If *e*−1 is negative, we multiply both sides by 2<sup>1−*e*</sup> to have 5•2<sup>1−*e*</sup> = 3•*M*. Then either 5 = 3•*M*•2<sup>*e*−1</sup> or 5•2<sup>1−*e*</sup> = 3•*M* is an equation having only integers, but the right side has a factor of 3 and the left side does not, which contradicts the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: `Note the radix point “.” after d0. This means the significand is in [0, b) and has p−1 digits after the radix point. (“[0, b)” denotes a half-open interval that includes 0 but excludes b.) Sometimes floating-point formats are described with the radix point in different positions, either before the first digit, .d0d−1d−2d−3…d1−p, or after the last digit, d0d−1d−2d−3…d1−p. These are equivalent mathematically:

d0.d−1d−2d−3…d1−p•be = .d0d−1d−2d−3…d1−p•be+1 = d0d−1d−2d−3…d1−p.•be+1−p.` Where is the radix point in the IEEE-754 `float `and `double` formats?

Comment: And does that mean that all whole numbers can be stored exactly in a floating point format?

Comment: @tempdevnova: The IEEE-754 standard generally uses the one-digit-before-point form but mentions the integer form. As noted, it is irrelevant mathematically.

Comment: @tempdevnova: Re “And does that mean that all whole numbers can be stored exactly in a floating point format?”: No. In the integer form, the significand M can be up to b^p−1. Any integer larger than that can be represented only if it has factors of b it can be divided by that are sufficiently to reduce it to an integer under b^p.

Comment: `For the IEEE-754 binary64 format, also called “double precision,” b is 2, p is 53, emin is −1022, and emax is 1023.

Using the integer-significand scaling, the exponent minimum and maximum are −1074 and 971. Then we can say a finite number can be represented in this format if and only if it equals M•2e for some integers M and e such that −253 < M < +253 and −1074 ≤ e ≤ 971.` I don't quite understand why there are two values for both e-min and e-max. For example is e-max 1023 or 971?