# Why is pytorch messing with my floats when I use t.item? I know about the precision errors, but 1.3 is such a tiny number

Tags: python, pytorch, floating-point

Pytorch is messing with my floats.

```
import torch
t = torch.FloatTensor([[1.3]])

print(t)
print(t.item())
```

prints

```
tensor([[1.3000]])
1.2999999523162842
```

I tried to use torch.Tensor([[1.3]]) as well and had the same issue. I don't get why 1.3 is something impossible to represent. Also torch.Tensor([[1.5]]) works just fine which is weird.

Comment: That's just the nature of floating point numbers and it's not unique to pytorch. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72729449/2542516

Comment: try `float(numpy.float32("1.3"))` and you'll get the same number back.  i.e. it's just using a single precision floating point number internally.  double precision would be 1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125, so still out a bit, even if it prints as 1.3 sometimes.  Eric's answers on this site are normally very good, I'd recommend spending some time understanding the one you were pointed to above

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you Priyatham and Sam!